# PrimeNG Calendar open Z index error

Tags: css, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using primeNG calendar and whenever the calendar opens under the input box it is behind all the other html elements. But when it opens above the input box everything is ok.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a StackBlitz please ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I fixed it by using  appendTo="body" in the p-calendar html element.

Here is how the html element looks like now:

```
 <p-calendar appendTo="body" [locale]="dk" placeholder="Inklusion dato" [(ngModel)]="patient.inclusionDate" showButtonBar="true"
      readonlyInput="true" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case works well. Just add inline CSS of

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateTo" [disabledDays]="[0,6]" (onSelect)="doOnSelect($event)" [showIcon]="true" [style]="{'overflow': 'visible', 'z-index': '9999','opacity':'1'}"></p-calendar>
```

Inline only work instead of working in style.css.